# Spring example of Map in which single key having multiple values

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I have to create a map in spring that single key has more than one value so ultimately it is of map on which key can have more than one value and we have to persist both of them , so i have design this in spring , please advise is it correct approach or there could be more better approach in this

below is the logic that  what i have design , please advise is the correct way

earlier it was  with a key having single value ..

```
<map>
                 <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>Deal Instrument</value>
                    </key>
                    <list>
                        <value>setpumentType</value>
                        <value>java.lang.String.class</value>
                    </list>
                </entry>

        </map>
```

and what i have editied it to have multiple values for a single key , as shown below

```
 <util:list id="list1">
      <value>setpumentType/value>
      <value>java.lang.String.class</value>
   </util:list>

   <util:list id="list2">
      <value>setReadType</value>
      <value>java.lang.String.class</value>
   </util:list>
```

and now I have added this list to a single key as shown below

```
   <map>
                 <entry>
                     <entry key="entry1" value-ref="list1" />
                     <entry key="entry1" value-ref="list2" />
                </entry>

        </map>
```

I have come up with this below approach also please advise is that also a correct approach

```
 <map>              
    <entry key="entry1" >

                     <util:list id="list1">
      <value>setpumentType/value>
      <value>java.lang.String.class</value>
   </util:list>

   <util:list id="list2">
      <value>setReadType</value>
      <value>java.lang.String.class</value>
   </util:list>                  
<entry />           

        </map>
```

Folks please advise for this. As I want to keep everything in configuration in xml itself

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with Spring. It has to do with understanding what Map is. It is a fundamental definition of Map that it can not have more then one key with the same value. What you may need if that your map needs to hold a pair of key-value where your value is a list. List can have multiple values. This actually vary typical. So you map may look something like:

`"key1" : List <"value1", "value2">
 "key2" : List <"value3", "value4">`

This seems to be what you require if I understood you correctly. At the same time this is absolutely standard map where there are no keys with the same value

Comment: Thanks  , yeah you got perfect i want to implement a map where a single key have multiple values , but please advise if my above spring implementation of map is wrong one then please advise how to correct this,Thanks in advance

Comment: i have edited my logic please go through that one also

Comment: sss your implementation doesn't look OK to me at a first glance as you shouldn't put String.class as a value but an actual String values. But I wouldn't put it in configuration at all. Just add a method to your class and annotate it with @postConstruct annotation, and in this method instantiate your Map<<String>, List<String>> with correct values and then assign it to your member variable

Comment: Thanks please ignore the values rite now I will definetly put string later that is just a configuration and please advise as I am using spring 2.1 jar which is mostly on xml bases so please advise my xml configuration is correct or not please

Comment: I want to put the things in configuration and that is also mostly in xml configuration please advise on this